# Wordpress - comment html code

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to comment html code?
I want to comment a img html tag or a video frame but everytime it gets filtered out. Is there any way that it doesn't get displayed? The html code should be executed that the image gets displayed itself and not the code

Answer (score 0):

Q: *Is it possible to comment html code?*

A: *Yes.*

Since you tagged yor question with `wordpress`, I'll show you how to comment in `PHP` codes too.

---

**HTML:**

```
<HTML><!--This is a comment. Comments are not displayed in the browser--></HTML>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php echo 'Print this'; //This is a comment. ?>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the code executed? I want to execute something like: <img src=""> so that it doesn't get printed. Instead it should be the image itself